# local frame can't use name bound in its parent frame

Tags: python

Came across python environment concept in a programming course and had a following question.

For example:

(1)

```
>>>def f(x):
       def g(y):
           return x - y
        return g
>>> f(2)(3)
-1
```

(2)

```
def f(x):
    def g(y):
        x = x - y
        return x
    return g
>>> f(2)(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in g
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

(3)

```
>>> def f(x):
        def g(y):
            if x > y:
               x = x - y
            else:
               x = y - x
            return x
        return g
>>> f(2)(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in g
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

example(1) can refer 'x' from its parent frame but the (2) and (3) can't. I couldn't figure out why. And if (2) fails because of assignment to a non-local name, why (3) gives an error at line 3, not line 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you 'refer' to a name in Python, you are implicitly performing an *unqualified name lookup*. These follow the LEGB rule: the system looks for *bindings* of the name in different places in the order

1. In the **L**ocal scope of the function in which the lookup is being done (if any)
2. In the local scope of functions **E**nclosing the one in which the lookup is being done (if any)
3. In the **G**lobal scope
4. In the **B**uiltins module.

The search stops as soon as it finds a binding of the name you seek. If the name is bound in more than one of those places, the earlier ones in the list are said to *shadow* the later ones.

In your first code sample, `x` is bound in **E**/`f` and `y` is bound in **L**/`g`. Both are parameters of functions, and function parameters are bound in the local scope of the function.

In your second sample `x =` binds the name `x` in the **L**ocal scope of the inner function `g`, thereby *shadowing* the binding of `x` in the **E**enclosing function `f`. Because of this, LEGB no longer finds `x` in **E**/`f` but in **L**/`g`.

By seeing the `x =` written inside `g` Python decides *at compile time* that `x`'s binding comes from `g`. Unfortunately, *at runtime* the binding of `x` in `g` has not been established yet. Which is why you get an `UnboundLocalError`.

In your third example, exactly the same problem occurs: On line 4 the compiler discovers that there is a binding of `x` in **L**/`g`, which shadows the binding of `x` in **E**/`f`, and therefore the binding of `x` in `g` will be used at runtime. At runtime we get to line 3 (where the name is looked up) before line 4 (where the name is bound), so once again `UnboundLocalError`.

The error is at line 3, because that is the line on which the lookup fails.

In summary, there is nothing wrong with assigning to `x` in `g`. The problem occurs when you try to lookup the value of `x` in `g` before it has been established.

*If* you are in Python 3, you could add the declaration `nonlocal x` inside the inner function `g`. This means: Dear compiler, if anywhere in this scope you find code that attempts to bind `x`, do not create a binding in *this* scope, instead, rebind the name in whatever enclosing scope has already provided the binding.

Comment: thank you so much @jacg, this is an excellent explain. Another question about python compiler and runtime, which I'm not familiar with. Does the *compiler* work from left to right (bind `x` first)? And during *runtime*, is the right hand of `=` evaluated first(`x = x - y` in ex2)? Then, it can't find `x` during *runtime* because `x` is bound to a local variable during *compile time* which hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: @Z.Chi At runtime the RHS of an assignment must be evaluated before the LHS is bound: how could the value be bound before it has been calculated! It's not really meaningful to say that the compiler works left-to-right in this case. What matters is that the compiler analyses the structure of the code before runtime. It's not quite what you say in your last sentence: the compiler does not bind `x`, but decides *where* `x` will be bound. Then the lookup happend before the binding at runtime.

Comment: @Z.Chi BTW, if you think that the answer is a good one, you should upvote it. If you think it solves your problem, then you should accept it.